# A set of sentences true under an arbitrarily large finite models, then it is true under some infinite model

Tags: logic, model-theory

Here is what I want to prove

> $\Sigma$ a set of sentences such that there are arbitrarily large finite models in which $\Sigma$ is true. Prove that $\Sigma$ is true in some infinite model.

Here is my attempt:

Let $A$ be the domain of model $\mathfrak{A}$. Let $|A|=n$ be the size of $\mathfrak{A}$. If $n=0$, then $A=\emptyset$ and we have no variable assignment to talk about. Given $n$, consider sentence $\mathcal{T}$ such that 
        \begin{align*}
   &\mathcal{T}:=\forall x_1\forall x_2\dots\forall x_n(\wedge_{j=1}^{n}\wedge_{i=1}^{n}(x_i\neq x_j))\text{ }\text{ when $n>1$}\\
   &\mathcal{T}:=\forall x_1 x_1=x_1\text{ }\text{ when $n=1$}
  \end{align*}
        where $\wedge_{j=1}^{n+1}\wedge_{i=1}^{n}(x_i\neq x_j)=(x_1\neq x_2)\wedge (x_1\neq x_3)\wedge\dots\wedge (x_1\neq x_{n})\wedge (x_2\neq x_1)\wedge\dots$

If $n=1$, then any model with a smaller size is empty. And for any model with at least size $n$, since $x_1=x_1$ is true under any variable assignments, hence $\mathcal{T}$ is true in these models.

For $n>1$, if size of $\mathfrak{B}$ is less than $n$, then there must be at least one pair of identical elements in $\{b_1,\dots, b_{n}\}\subseteq B$ by Pigeonhole principle. Hence for any variable assignment $s$, if $s'\equiv s$ except $s'(x_i)=b_i$ $\forall 1\leq i\leq n$, then $s'(x_{i})=b_i= b_j=s'(x_{j})$ for some $1\leq i\neq j\leq n$. Hence $\mathcal{T}$ is never true in these model. If size of $\mathfrak{B}$ is at least $n$, then we can choose $\{b_1,\dots, b_{n}\}\subseteq B$ be pairwise distinct so that for any variable assignment $s$, if $s'\equiv s$ except $s'(x_i)=b_i$ $\forall 1\leq i\leq n$, then $s'(x_{i})=b_i\neq b_j=s'(x_{j})$ for all $1\leq i\neq j\leq n$, i.e. $\mathcal{T}$ is true under $s$ in $\mathfrak{B}$.

Now for each $n$, we get a sentence $\mathcal{T}$ that is true in all and only those models that have size $\geq n$. Let $\Sigma$ be a set of $\mathcal{T}$ for all $n$. Hence any finite subset of $\Sigma$ is true under some infinite model, so satisfiable. By Compactness, we know if every finite subset of a set of sentences is satisfiable then, the whole set is satisfiable, so we done.

My questions: Since $\Sigma$ is true under some arbitrarily large finite models, so I assume that for each $n$, every sentence in it is true in all model with size greater than $n$. However, I specifically choose my sentences to construct the $\Sigma$ instead of consider case in general. So am I wrong? And what will be a sentence look like in general such that given $n$, it is true in all and only those models that have size $\geq n$. Thanks in advance.

==============update======================

Thanks @Asaf Karagila for pointing out the mistakes on the quantifier. $\mathcal{T}$ should be $\exists x_1\exists x_2\dots\exists x_n(\wedge_{j=1}^{n}\wedge_{i=1}^{n}(x_i\neq x_j))\text{ }\text{ when $n>1$}$. And the rest follow. And as mentioned by @Alex Kruckman, my question is a duplicate of a question asked by @MrTopology. I follow his idea to finish the problem in general case

Now for each $n$, we get a sentence $\mathcal{T}$ that is true in all and only those models that have size $\geq n$. Let $\Sigma^*$ be collection of  $\mathcal{T}$ for all $n$. Hence $\Sigma^*$ is true in infinite model. Let $\overline{\Sigma}=\Sigma^*\bigcup\Sigma$. As $\Sigma$ is a set of sentences such that there are arbitrarily large finite models in which it is true, any finite subset of $\overline{\Sigma}$ is true under some finite model, so satisfiable. By Compactness, we know if every finite subset of a set of sentences is satisfiable then, the whole set is satisfiable, so $\overline{\Sigma}$ satisfiable. Since $\Sigma^*$ is true only in some infinite model under construction, hence $\overline{\Sigma}$ is true in some infinite model, then so is $\Sigma$

Comment: Your heart is in the right place, but you wrote $\forall$ where you really should have written $\exists$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila So you mean $\exists x_1\exists x_2\dots\exists x_n(\wedge_{j=1}^{n}\wedge_{i=1}^{n}(x_i\neq x_j))=\neg\forall x_1\forall x_2\dots\forall x_n(\vee_{j=1}^{n}\vee_{i=1}^{n}(x_i= x_j))$?

Comment: You want to say that there exist *at least* $n$ elements, right?

Comment: The model have to have at least n elements in order to make $\mathcal{T}$ to be true under a variable assignment which assigns distinct element form the model to each variable. And this will show my set of such sentence $\mathcal{T}$ is true in infinite model.

Comment: And saying that *every* $n$ elements are different from one another is true, how? If you have one element, then use it as a value for all the $x_i$'s...

Comment: I am getting a little bit confused. If a model consists of less than n elements, then no matter what variable assignment I choose (either assigning same values to all variable or something else), I have to have two variables assigned the same value, hence my $\mathcal{T}$ is false. If the model has at least n elements, then I can choose my variable assignment which assigns distinct value to each distinct variable to make my $\mathcal{T}$ be true, so it is true in every such model

Comment: Okay, try to prove that in $\{0,1\}$ the statement $\forall x\forall y(x\neq y)$ is false. The language, if that matters, is only with equality.

Comment: Oh, now I see what's wrong, I mess up with these two quantifiers. Thanks!